# Undefined variable: image_name Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, image-upload

I want to upload and display image, but i get error 
Undefined variable: image_name

This is my controller

```
$supply = new DataSupplyProcess;
    if($request->hasFile('supply_photo')){
            $photo = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'supply_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
    if($photo->fails()){
                return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'Image size should be 2MB or less');
        }            
        $image = $request->file('supply_photo');
        $image_name = rand().'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destination_path = public_path('/item');
        $image->move($destination_path, $image_name);
        //dd($image);

    }
        $supply->item = $request->item;
        $supply->supply_details = $request->supply_details;
        $supply->tgl_request_date = $request->tgl_need_date;
        $supply->tgl_need_date = $request->tgl_need_date;
        $supply->employee_id = $id;
        $supply->id_approved_by = $manager->employee_manager_id;
        $supply->is_approved = 0;
        $supply->is_final_approved = 0;
        $supply->supply_photo = $image_name;
        $supply->save();
```

This Is My View

```
  <label for="supply_photo">Photo</label>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" class="form-control" name="supply_photo">
```

Comment: If you don't upload any file, `$image_name` has not been created yet and PHP will complain

Comment: but i upload image

Comment: `dd($request->hasFile('supply_photo'))` and post what does it return

Comment: @MateusJunges the return is false

Comment: Now you knows why `$image_name` is undefined.

Comment: Can you `dd($request->all())` to see what data is inside the request, also can you post your html form? there could be a problem with your front end.

Comment: @catcon i dd and get
**bold**
array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "RgPVBkj9eyVAijSv1rxnWd77kRX3vG11xr2LAvqa"
  "item" => "1"
  "tgl_request_date" => "2019-07-11"
  "tgl_need_date" => "2019-07-12"
  "supply_details" => "1"
  "supply_photo" => "photo_2019-06-25_11-01-55.jpg"
]

Comment: As you can see, your `supply_photo` is only a string, it should be an instance of `UploadFile` in order to `$request->hasFile()` return true

Comment: sorry, can you give me example for that?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try something like:

```php
if(Input::file('supply_photo') !== null){
    $photo = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'supply_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
    ...
}
```

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668709/how-to-save-images-in-laravel/56669280#56669280) can provide more info

Comment: Can you `dd($request->all())` and post the response?

Comment: i dd and get 
**array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "RgPVBkj9eyVAijSv1rxnWd77kRX3vG11xr2LAvqa"
  "item" => "1"
  "tgl_request_date" => "2019-07-11"
  "tgl_need_date" => "2019-07-12"
  "supply_details" => "1"
  "supply_photo" => "photo_2019-06-25_11-01-55.jpg"
]**

Answer (score 0):

when ever you pass variable like this with **IF** condition assign default value first.
so you won't get error if image not selected.

and in your cause check first you get image or not

```
dd($image = $request->file('supply_photo'));

$image_name = NULL;

if($request->hasFile('supply_photo')){

        $image = $request->file('supply_photo');
        $image_name = rand().'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destination_path = public_path('/item');
        $image->move($destination_path, $image_name);

}

$supply->supply_photo = $image_name;
$supply->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$supply = new DataSupplyProcess;

if($request->hasFile('supply_photo')){
        $photo = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'supply_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

         if($photo->fails()){
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'Image size should be 2MB or less');
         }  

         //$original_name=$request->file('supply_photo')->getClientOriginalName();
         //$size=$request->file('supply_photo')->getSize();
         $extension=$request->file('supply_photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $filename=uniqid().'.'.$extension;
         $imagepath=url('/item/'.$filename);
         $path=$request->file('supply_photo')->storeAs(public_path('/item'),$filename);



}
```